# How can I implement this where I print this message every __ seconds __ times?

Tags: python, schedule

I want to call the printFunction method every __ seconds, but I want to stop the scheduling after a certain number of calls. Say for example, print every 5 seconds 10 times. Pulling those frequency and run time values in from another file.

Running in PyCharm.

import schedule 
import time

class example:

```
# basic function to print
def printFunction(self):
    print("Hello world")

def repeated(self):
    # reads in two values from another file
    systemFrequency = float(freqSettings.systemFrequency)
    systemRunTime = int(freqSettings.systemRunTime)
    global count 
    count = 0

    while (count < systemRunTime): 
        self.printFunction
        self.increaseCount


 def increaseCount(self):
    global count
    count += 1
```

Comment: And the problem is....?

Comment: Calls to self currently print "hello world" __ times immediately as opposed to waiting a set amount of seconds

Answer (score 0):

The function run by the scheduler need to return CancelJob to stop being scheduled.

Here is how i've implemented it :

```
import schedule

def my_function():
    print("hello world")

def wrapper():
    wrapper.counter +=1
    my_function()
    if wrapper.counter == 10:
        return schedule.CancelJob
wrapper.counter = 0

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(wrapper)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    print(schedule)
```

It displays 10 "hello world"